# How to display the timer in android

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I want to display the timer in TextView in the format of like [ 19:59].so when i click the start button ,the timer will display like this for example,i want to set upto 20 mintues,it will display like [19:58][19:87].can anyone give some ideas or example code?[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: Can you show us what you have?

Comment: most of the example stars with starting time like 1,2,3 seconds uptp 60 seconds.i want reverse order

Comment: @rajeshlawrance check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: can u give some example code?

Comment: @rajeshlawrance check my answer. but there is no pause for the timer. you need to cancel and restart. probably store the value when you cancel and provide the value when you restart.

Comment: @rajeshlawrance did you try the below?

Comment: Checkout this: https://github.com/Shubhamsdr3/timertextview

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `CountDownTimer`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
     TextView _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
    new CountDownTimer(20*60000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            _tv.setText("seconds remaining: " +new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SS").format(new Date( millisUntilFinished)));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
           _tv.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();
```

To cancel just call cancel on the timer.

`public final void cancel()`

Cancel the countdown.

Comment: Can this be used to make a count up timer? i.e. starting from 0 and goes to infinity

Comment: @RuchirBaronia the first argument takes a long which is milliseconds for testing i used that. You can change it to  whatever you feel right

Comment: So that is how much time the timer will go right? Why not just say: `1200000` instead?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia you can do that.

Comment: Why is it `mm:ss:SS`? Thanks

Comment: Check the DateFormats in java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: So will this display something like so if I set it at 20 seconds? 20:59 -> 20:58 Every millisecond update?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia yes. timer task always run in background and with callbacks you update ui

Comment: So will this display something like so if I set it at 20 seconds? 20:59 -> 20:58 Every millisecond update?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia try it yourself you will see the result

Comment: Reason I'm asking is because whenever I use count down timer, it is inaccurate. It will go by 12 or 15 milliseconds off everytime. That is why I'm asking, is this accurate?

Answer (score 17):

```
package com.example.testproject;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int seconds = 60;
    public int minutes = 10;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Declare the timer
        Timer t = new Timer();
        //Set the schedule function and rate
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_timer_text);
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(minutes)+":"+String.valueOf(seconds));
                        seconds -= 1;

                        if(seconds == 0)
                        {
                            tv.setText(String.valueOf(minutes)+":"+String.valueOf(seconds));

                            seconds=60;
                            minutes=minutes-1;

                        }



                    }

                });
            }

        }, 0, 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is the code i tried and i got the answer with my own logic

Comment: little bit mistake: second -= 1 must be after if(seconds == 0){...}, else your timer's second will show 0 after 2

Comment: Why you are initializing `TextView` every time in run method.

Answer (score 7):

do it this way activity_timer.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

And in Activity

```
public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private Chronometer chronometer2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

        chronometer2 = findViewById(R.id.chronometer2);
        chronometer2.start();
    }
}
```

You can also use stop

```
chronometer2.stop();
```

Re Start

```
chronometer2.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
 chronometer2.start();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  //start button click
     CountDown timer = new CountDown(180000, 1000);
     timer.start();

//stop button click
timer.stop();   

    //countdown class
    public class CountDown extends CountDownTimer {

          public CountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
             super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
          }

          @Override
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             long ms = millisUntilFinished;
             String text = String.format("%02d\' %02d\"",
                                         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(ms) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(ms)),
                                         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(ms) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(ms)));
             textViewTimer.setText(text);
          }

          @Override
          public void onFinish() {
             textViewTimer.setText("ffinish");
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have use Timer class to display timer

```
    public class FourthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button startButton, pauseButton;
    TextView timerValue;
    Timer timer;
    int seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hour = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fourth);
        bindView();

        timer = new Timer();
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (seconds == 60) {
                                    timerValue.setText(String.format("%02d", hour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                                    minutes = seconds / 60;
                                    seconds = seconds % 60;
                                    hour = minutes / 60;
                                }
                                seconds += 1;
                                timerValue.setText(String.format("%02d", hour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    private void bindView() {
        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    }
}
```

In layout, there are one TextView and one Button to start timer. I have use Timer class method `scheduleAtFixedRate`. Time will be displayed in hh:mm:ss form.

Comment: not correct, minutes can not increase more than 1. you should ++ it in if statement, same problem for hours

Answer (score 1):

Showing timer in Kotlin.

```
class TimerDemo : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityTimerDemoBinding
private lateinit var timer: Timer
private var seconds = 0
private var secondsToDisplay = 0
private var minutes = 0
private var hours = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityTimerDemoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    configureTimer()
}

private fun configureTimer() {
    timer = Timer().apply {
        scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                runOnUiThread {
                    if (seconds % 60 == 0) {
                        binding.tvTimerValue.text =
                            "${String.format("%02d", hours)} :" +
                                    " ${String.format("%02d", minutes)} :" +
                                    " ${String.format("%02d", secondsToDisplay)}"
                        minutes = seconds / 60
                        secondsToDisplay %= 60;
                        hours = minutes / 60
                    }
                    seconds++
                    secondsToDisplay++
                    binding.tvTimerValue.text =
                        "${String.format("%02d", hours)} :" +
                                " ${String.format("%02d", minutes)} :" +
                                " ${String.format("%02d", secondsToDisplay)}"
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000)
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    binding.btnStopTimer.setOnClickListener { timer.cancel() }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [**cronometer**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html),  the most main reason is supporting **API 1+**, which is quite impressive rather than **TextClock**, which supports **API 17+**.

You can do lots of other things with cronometer. **for example** you can set start time in it

> chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

You can also learn about it more [**here.**](http://androidbreakdown.blogspot.in/2017/05/chronometer-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

I made code for timer display in textView.The formate is for e.g:- `02:59:00`

You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58316149/11613683) to get the `Step By Step` Code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58316149/11613683