# display current date n time in text view without any event - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

> I have textview i want to display the current date n time but without on click even on button as soon as app is launched it should start ticking date n time

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
textView.setText(currentDateTimeString);
```

Comment: try with this   public static String getCurrentDateAndTime() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    }

Comment: but this will still not start date time ticker when the app launches.. it will reply on some events.. i want to start ticker on textview as soon as app launches

Comment: you can use thread or handler to implement this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480936/how-to-display-the-timer-in-android

Comment: If you need to do something other than just show the time you might want to look into a TimerTask. If it is just to track time there are native widgets that handle that.

Answer (score 4):

use  TextClock

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

just put on your layout

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#d41709"
    android:textSize="44sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Pay attention that TextClock was added in API 17.
In case you are using earlier, try DigitalClock
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html

Answer (score 1):

Add the code to the onCreate method of your main activity. This code runs when the app is launched.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        <<<<your date and time logic>>>>>

   }
```

http://factualnote.com/f/j2ci4rrd0unqhfftc74k4ltgh

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
TextView textViewDisplayDate;
long date = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM MM dd, yyyy h:mm a");
String dateString = sdf.format(date);   
textViewDisplayDate.setText(dateString);
```

which displays in the following example format:-
`Thu Oct 10, 2019 11:46 AM`

You can use whatever format you want - options can be found [at Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)