# How to display a timer in a TextView in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, timer

I want to set this textview:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/directions"/>
```

To be a timer.  So the text should be a timer going like 0:30 then 0:29 ... for 30 seconds.  Once timer is 0:00, I can call another method; I can print out "try again" and restart timer.

Comment: Check CountDown Timer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: Check this: http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-count-down-timer-example.html

Comment: Check great answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/how-to-set-timer-in-android

Comment: See, if this might be useful: https://github.com/Shubhamsdr3/timertextview

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
int time=30;
TextView textTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
        textTimer.setText("0:"+checkDigit(time));
        time--;         
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textTimer.setText("try again");
    }

}.start();



public String checkDigit(int number) {
    return number <= 9 ? "0" + number : String.valueOf(number);
}
```

Comment: what does checkDigit do?

Comment: there's an extra paranthesees on try again

Comment: it convert int data in double digit...like when your counter is 8, so this function will convert to "08", simply it add zero before single digit. so we can display double digits...like...09..08..07.....00.

Comment: is there a way to restart the timer? like by calling some method?

Answer (score 6):

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mtextTimer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView textTimer;

    private Button StartTimer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing the views
        textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mtextTimer);

        StartTimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

        StartTimer.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        long maxTimeInMilliseconds = 30000;// in your case

        startTimer(maxTimeInMilliseconds, 1000);

    }

    public void startTimer(final long finish, long tick) {
        CountDownTimer t;
        t = new CountDownTimer(finish, tick) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long remainedSecs = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                textTimer.setText("" + (remainedSecs / 60) + ":" + (remainedSecs % 60));// manage it accordign to you
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                textTimer.setText("00:00:00");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                cancel();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int seconds = 60;
    public int minutes = 10;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Declare the timer
        Timer t = new Timer();
        //Set the schedule function and rate
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_timer_text);
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(minutes)+":"+String.valueOf(seconds));
                        seconds -= 1;

                        if(seconds == 0)
                        {
                            tv.setText(String.valueOf(minutes)+":"+String.valueOf(seconds));

                            seconds=60;
                            minutes=minutes-1;

                        }



                    }

                });
            }

        }, 0, 1000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 long MillisecondTime, TimeBuff, UpdateTime = 0L;
 int Seconds, Minutes, MilliSeconds;
 TextView textViewTimer = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);

 public void startTimer() {
    new CountDownTimer(180000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            MillisecondTime = millisUntilFinished;

            UpdateTime = TimeBuff + MillisecondTime;

            Seconds = (int) (UpdateTime / 1000);

            Minutes = Seconds / 60;

            Seconds = Seconds % 60;

            MilliSeconds = (int) (UpdateTime % 1000);

            textViewTimer.setText("0" + Minutes + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", Seconds) + ":"
                    + String.format("",MilliSeconds));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
             textViewTimer.setText("Done!");

        }
    }.start();


}
```

Call `startTimer()`  method and this will set `timer` to `textView` for e.g. start time 02:59:00

Answer (score 2):

```
public void settimer() {
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long remainedSecs = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            forgotpasswordBinding.txtotptime.setText("" + (remainedSecs / 60) + ":" + (remainedSecs % 60));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            forgotpasswordBinding.txtotptime.setText("Resend");
            forgotpasswordBinding.txtotptime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            settimer();
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Timer t = new Timer();    //declare the timer
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { //Set the schedule function and rate

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView mRefreshTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.screenStatusTvTime);
                    mRefreshTime.setText(String.format("%dh%02d'%02d\"", minutes/60, minutes%60, seconds));
                    if (++seconds == 60) {
                        seconds = 0;
                        minutes++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0L, 1000L);
```

Comment: Please include actual answer to the question, not just the code. You can further improve your answer by adding some comments and/or explanation to the code provided. In the meanwhile, have a look at [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
timer will set for 3min like "2:59"
    private int time=60,n=2; 

        textTimer=findViewById(R.id.timer);
        // textview 
                    new CountDownTimer(180000, 1000) {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            if(time==0)
                            {
                                n--;
                                time=60;
                            }

                            textTimer.setText( n +":" + checkdigit(time));
                            time--;
                        }
                        public void onFinish() {

                        }
                    }.start();
     public String checkdigit(int number)
        {
            return number <= 9 ? "0" + number : String.valueOf(number);
        }
```

Comment: Hello welcome to SO, can you give a brief description of how your answer is supposed to help OP?